# Something went wrong!Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function For HOC

Tags: javascript, reactjs, higher-order-components

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import CreateProject from './CreateProjectWithName';

function Enhanced(WrappedComponent) {
  // ...and returns another component...
  return class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        data: []
      };
    }


    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent data={this.state.data} {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
}
const Wrapper = (props) => {
  const Comp = Enhanced(<CreateProject />);
  return (
    <div>

      <Comp />

      <div>
        {/* <button onClick={() => updateView()} /> */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

This code block just won't work. What am I doing wrong? Which principal fundamental of React am I missing out on? What is the correct way of rendering an HOC?

Comment: `const Comp = Enhanced(CreateProject);`

Answer (score 1):

The HOC takes in a component reference what you are providing it is an instance when you use it like

```
const Comp = Enhanced(<CreateProject />);
```

The correct way would be

```
const Comp = Enhanced(CreateProject);
```

Also for performance reasons and for proper execution of lifecycle you must create a wrapped component with HOC outside of your component

```
const Comp = Enhanced(CreateProject);
const Wrapper = (props) => {

  return (
    <div>

      <Comp />

      <div>
        {/* <button onClick={() => updateView()} /> */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function Enhanced(WrappedComponent) {
  // ...and returns another component...
  return class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {
        data: []
      };
    }


    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent data={this.state.data} {...this.props} />;
    }
  };
}
const Wrapper = (props) => {
  const Comp = Enhanced(CreateProject );
  return (
    <div>

      <Comp />

      <div>
        {/* <button onClick={() => updateView()} /> */}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
```